# Templates for emails in Java

Tags: java, email, velocity

We are building a web application which also sends emails based on different scenarios. I am checking various options for setting templates for mails (i.e. mail content, subject). I have gone through the below options:

- **Apache Velocity**: Using this, I can set templates for email content, but how can I also set the subject for the mails? I need to call another template to set subject. Is there any way by which I can specify the mail body and the subject without using two different template files?
- **Database driven templates**: Main disadvantage is that we need to reinvent the wheel in this approach. We'll end up writing boilerplate code for which utilities are already available.

We don't need any hi-fi stuff, just simple templating. Only requirement is we should be able to send different mails with different subjects as per scenarios. Any suggestions?

Comment: It depends what you are using for sending emails. You could have an entire email, with all headers, as a template, and then just raw-read it, fill the values, and send. If your email library allows it.

Comment: I had used `StringTemplate` http://www.stringtemplate.org/about.html long ago and it was easy to use. Check if it suffices your needs.

Comment: An email subject is always one line. You could adopt the convention that the first line of the result is the subject, and that the rest is the body. Not sure if that would make it clearer than using a different file, though.

Comment: You can use freemarker template files for your different scenario's, and use accordingly.

Comment: Uh "reinventing the wheel" is an overstatement for this. It is incredibly simple to accomplish so you create your own solution. I would be surprised if it takes longer than an hour to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ended up implementing database driven templates. We now have defined the templates and placeholders in 2 tables, and a generic utility that reads the templates and substitutes the placeholders at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with velocity in the past and it's much better than reinventing the wheel.

If you use velocity, you have three options:

1. Create one template per subject and one template per body
2. Split the template file before sending it to velocity (e.g. all lines until "____" are subject, rest body
3. Split the output (e.g. first line = subject, rest body) on velocity's output

The first option is the easiest to set up, but will double your amount of templates. The second one is the hardest to get wrong. The third one has the best performance characteristics, but you may accidentally miss the split criteria, putting the whole email in the subject or otherwise mess it up.

Edit: Following nablex' comment, I'd like to expand on the motivation: Yes, you may start out with super simple stuff like replacing "<>" with the recipients' username or something, but soon enough the client invariably asks for more complex stuff ("can we have a table with the order items?"). Before you know it, you're [Greenspunning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule) your own language. Therefore, it is advisable to reuse what those who already have been burned came up with.

Comment: I am curious: what are the advantages that you notice versus a custom solution for this? It seems like a **very** simple usecase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this area, but I've used [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/). It's pretty cool and fast. I think you'll be able to fulfill your requirement easily.